# Using a JTable causes rest of the application to load incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

First off, this is for a school project so I can't upload my full code. We've been given a blank project and asked to add functionality to it.

I want to be able to display data from a sever in various tables, each one in a separate tab, with each 'page' having the option to add, edit or delete records to the table.

As I have quite a few different tables, I wrote a parent class, Page, that will contain a table and some JPanels that I can add buttons to if needed.

However whenever I try adding a JTable to Page, it causes unpredictable behaviour between the tabs - note this happens regardless of whether or not I use a TableModel.

I tried using labels to display where the components should be, which works fine, but using actual tables causes the placeholder labels and the tabs at the top to be hidden.

[Tab with labels to illustrate where the components SHOULD be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQCjA.png)

[Tab after I try to add a JTable - the rest of the code (including other placeholder labels) is the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJor1.png)

I haven't done anything with threading, so am at a loss as to what's happening to the application when I try to add my JTable.

This is the code for Page.java:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Page extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4661566573959270000L;
    protected JTable table;
    protected JPanel addPanel;
    protected JPanel fieldPanel;
    protected JPanel buttonPanel;
    protected TableModel model;
    public Page(String[] names) {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        final class MyTableModel implements TableModel{
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4661566573959270000L;
            private String[] columnNames;
            private Object[][] data;
            public MyTableModel(String[] names) {
                columnNames=names;
                data=new Object[names.length][0];
            }
            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if(isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex)) {
                    data[rowIndex][columnIndex] = aValue;
                }
             }     

             @Override
             public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {

             }

             @Override
             public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                      return false;
             }

             @Override
             public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                 return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
             }

             @Override
             public int getRowCount() {
                 return data.length;
             }

             @Override
             public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
                 return columnNames[columnIndex];
             }

             @Override
             public int getColumnCount() {
                 return columnNames.length;
             }

             @Override
             public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                 try {
                     return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                     return null;
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {

             }
         };


         /**
         * creating and adding a table
         * this is the problematic bit
         */
         table = new JTable(new MyTableModel(names));
         this.add(table);
         //this.add(new Label("Table"));



         //panels for layout
         addPanel = new JPanel();
         fieldPanel = new JPanel();
         buttonPanel = new JPanel();
         //assigning positions
         this.add(addPanel);
         addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         addPanel.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         addPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         //placeholder labels
         fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Insert fields here"));
         buttonPanel.add(new Button("Buttons"));
     }
 }
```

I add new pages to my tab system with the following code:

```
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
tabs.add("A", new Page(new String[]{"A"}));
tabs.add("B", new Page(new String[]{"B"}));
tabs.add("C", new Page(new String[]{"C"}));
tabs.add("D", new Page(new String[]{"D"}));
```

With the String[] being the names of the columns that I want to display - note these will be replaced with actual helpful names once I've got the tables working properly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I've tried repainting my frame with a ChangeListener event, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thank you!

***EDIT***
Included is a complete version of the code. Use the above code for Page, and use this in a Main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Components and Containers");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
        window.setSize(800,600);

        Container pane = window.getContentPane();
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.add("A", new Page(new String[]{"A"}));
        tabs.add("B", new Page(new String[]{"B"}));
        tabs.add("C", new Page(new String[]{"C"}));
        tabs.add("D", new Page(new String[]{"D"}));
        pane.add(tabs);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried adding the table to a ScrollPanel instead, and the table only becomes visible when you hover over it. The tabs are still not showing correctly.

[The result of adding the table to a separate ScrollPanel instead of directly to the component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTAC2.png)

Comment: Hi bSmtih. It is a good idea to create a [MCVE] to include in your question. That is the best way to help us help you.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show for how to add a table to a container.

Comment: There might be other problems, but the statements `this.add(addPanel); addPanel = new JPanel();` are definitively out of sequence (you need to create the `addPanel` before trying to add it to the page).

Comment: @ThomasKläger I changed the order I'd written the code in for better formatting when asking my question, so this wasn't the problem - good spot though!

Comment: It's difficult to judge with the given code, but those lines :  public MyTableModel(String[] names) {
                columnNames=names;
                data=new Object[names.length][0];
            } seems to conflict with tabs.add("D", new Page(new String[]{"D"})); if the Page constructor call the MyTableModel constructor, because all the Object array will have the same length, thus the same index.

Comment: @TT. see edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table model class is inconsistent with respect to the row/column ordering.

In the constructor, you write

```
data=new Object[names.length][0];
```

which implies that the first index is the column number and the second index is the row number.

However, when accessing the data (in `getValueAt`, `setValueAt`), you use the indizes in the other way round:

```
data[rowIndex][columnIndex]
```

And also, this:

```
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.length;
}
```

returns the column count as row count, which means you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as soon as the JTable tries to call `getValueAt(0, 0)`.

---

To fix the problem, you should initialize the data array in the constructor with:

```
data=new Object[0][names.length];
```